# Can't browse windows network from OSX

Tags: windows-7, windows, macos, networking, osx-snow-leopard

**Here's the situation:**

I've got a Windows PC (running Win 7) that I want to be able to see from my Mac (running Snow Leopard). I've been through all the tutorials about how to get it working, and I can successfully connect via **"cmd-k"**.

However the windows PC is not automatically appearing in Finder as it should, and hence I'm not able to add a printer shared from that computer.

-

**What I've Tried:**

I'm fairly certain that all of the settings are OK on my Mac - I've taken it to a friend's place where it works as expected - so I'm assuming it's something to do with the settings on the windows PC. I can see it via the cmd-k option, so it's connecting ok - it's just not finding the Windows PC automatically like it should.

I've tried turning off antivirus, making sure bonjour is installed etc - what might I be missing? Also are there any tests I could run to help locate the issue?

-

Thanks - any help is much appreciated!

Comment: To me the Finder sidebar also seems like a very unreliable way to locate network shares. My Windows 7 machine also doesn't show up most of the time. I couldn't really find out what causes it (yet). Once connected, can you access its shares through the sidebar though?

Comment: Yes - it stays there just like a flash drive would. I don't mind that so much, the issue is more that I can't add a printer shared from the windows PC until the windows PC is connected 'properly' (and is recognized by the printer setup utility as a networked windows PC)

Comment: Hm, maybe let's try to get some more information about the Windows share. I don't know if it's of any good use, but it's good to have as many diagnostics as possible. Try to run `smbclient -L <host> -U <user> -d=3` from the Terminal, where `<host>` is the Windows hostname and `<user>` is the user name by which you connect (or "guest) &ndash; then edit your question and add this information. It doesn't hurt to have.

Comment: Check the windows naming daemon log on OS X, /private//var/log/samba/log.nmbd (viewable in the Console utility if you show the Log List sidebar), and see if it looks any different when joining/using your net vs. your friend's.  Also, check the workgroup name of your Mac (in the Network preferences) vs. that of the PCs involved.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try both these things when I get home tonight - hopefully something from the stats/logs should point to where the problem is. I've already made sure that the workgroup names are the same.